# Printing nested object on angular 8 table

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object

Hello guys i have http response coming from mongo db and i fetch values like

```
loadOrders(){
    this.orderService.getOrders()
      .subscribe((data:any[])=>{
        this.orders=data;
      }   
      );
  }
```

in orders-list component.html and im printing values into the table like :

```
  <tr *ngFor='let order of orders'>
            <td>{{order.name}}</td>
            <td>{{order.basket}}</td>
            <td>{{order.address}}</td>
            <td>{{order.total}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <button (click)="deleteOrder(order._id)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">Delete</span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

values like name , adress shown but when i trying to access orders.basket it is printing table like : 
    [object Object] i tried several ways  like mapping whole array but when i did that the other values didn't shown correctly and this is full output of my basket response :

```
  basket:
    5e839d3b268ce30ef066cb84:
    item:
    name: "Pizza"
    price: 25
    quantity: 501
    __v: 0
    _id: "5e839d3b268ce30ef066cb84"
```

I want to access basket - > item object in table.
Thanks for all answers.

Edit : Screenshot added.

[image]

Edit : I tried to acces object with

```
<td *ngFor = "let subItem of order.basket">{{subItem.basket.name}}</td>
```

but i get Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. Error

Comment: what exactly is in `orders.basket`?

Comment: The response from your API is not so clear. Could you clarify a bit, please, the form of basket?

Comment: i edited question you can see orders.basket contents

Comment: @DenizFirat: A screenshot would be a better fit here. Lack of indentations isn't helping either.

Comment: What you want to display? name or all details?

Comment: Just change `<td>{{order.basket}}</td>` to this `<td>{{order.basket.name}}</td>` You can access other attributes in a similar way

Comment: @Nikhil i tried this but it printed undefined

Comment: @Supercool. i want to display item name and price

Comment: @DenizFirat My bad. I just rechecked your screenshot. You actually have a complex scenario. The key that could iterate through changes for each item in the basket array. You will have to use the `Object.values()` to separate out the core item object. Or get the `Object.keys()` and then access each `basket` value as `basket[key].item.name`

Comment: @Nikhil when i console.logged Object.keys() it has only one key like ["0"] i tried pipe to transform and seperate data but i didn't work too. I think i need convert all of the data to array but i can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation of extracting the `keys` using `Object.keys()` and displaying the `basket` items. Please refer to the Stackblitz link for the full code.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Basket</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor='let order of orders'>
        <td>{{order.name}}</td>
        <td>
            <div *ngFor="let key of getKeys(order.basket)">
                {{ order.basket[key].item.name }}
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>{{order.address}}</td>
        <td>{{order.total}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

TS

```
  getKeys(obj: any): Array<string> {
    return Object.keys(obj);
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-inzfdw

Comment: I implemented your solution and it works perfect i can access all values in basket array thank you.